# How can i accept null data when searching a collection in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crm

I am currently building a very small CRM for practice and i'm trying to make a page you can search profiles in. i want the user to enter all the data he knows about the profile he is looking up but allow him not to fill every input. When i tried to fetch data from MongoDB without 1 field it returned null, what can i do about it?

````
    name: String,
    email: String,
    date: String,
    notes: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('profiles', createProfile)```

this is the schema

    await mongo().then( async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            console.log('Finding data from MongoDB')
            
            const result = await createProfile.findOne({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                notes: req.body.notes

            })
            console.log(result)
            res.redirect('/find')
        } catch {
            console.log('Can not connect')
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
this is the operation
````

Comment: i'm doing a search

Comment: Ok, so is the issue that `name`, `email`, or `notes` can be undefined?  And they are defined in the database?

Comment: the issue is that they cant be null so you have to answer all of the inputs in the operation to get an object

Comment: Right, because you are including them on the query.  If they are null and you don't want to find elements that have a null value for that key, don't include it on the query

Comment: i know but i want to make it optional so you can still search without the field or with

Comment: i can create if statements but that's not a good solution

Comment: That is the solution.  You only include the keys on the query that you want to match against.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = {};

['name', 'email', 'notes'].forEach(key => {
    if (req.body[key]) {
        query[key] = req.body[key];
    }
});

const result = await createProfile.findOne(query);
```

Only include the keys that the user provides a value for.